# Android <button> not filling area defined for it

Tags: android, button, formatting, styling

I am new to Android dev and am having trouble formatting some buttons.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/char_str_plus"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/char_str_min"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

As you can see from the pic the button does not fill the blue square. I'm not sure why. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What are the layout params for the container that button is in?

Comment: I've added the layout to my code. Not much there so I hope that's not it.

Comment: It looks as if there are little exclamation marks on each button that may indicate a problem. If you hover the mouse over them does Eclipse (or whatever IDE you're using) give any cludes

Comment: That's just because I hard coded the "+" and "-" instead of using @string

Comment: Can you upload the full layout xml?

Comment: I can, but I took another's advice and used ImageButton instead and they are working great now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will work, but you can try this:

```
android:scaleType="fitEnd"
```

Thats what I use on imagebuttons.

Comment: It's not an ImageButton I think, he is using "-" and "+" as text.

Comment: yeah, I see, however, why not consider using an imagebutton in this case ? It should fix the problem.

Comment: I will eventually use image button so I guess I will just use placeholder image for now since I can't seem to get this working.